# Finding connected components in 2D integer coordinate system

Tags: graphs-and-networks, image-processing

Let `L` be a finite set of *pair of integers*.

I want to partition `L` according to connectivity

The connectivity is intuitive :

Rule1
`(l1,l2)`,`(l3,l4)` is connected if
`(l1-l3, l2-l4)` equals to one of `(0,1)`,`(0,-1)`,`(1,0)`,`(-1,0)`.

Rule2
If `(l1,l2)`,`(l3,l4)` is connected and `(l3,l4)`,`(l5,l6)` is connected, then `(l1,l2)`,`(l5,l6)` is connected

(auxiliary rule : Only consider Rule1, Rule2.)

I know two methods, but I am not satisfied perfectly for both methods.

***method 1)***
`MorphologicalComponents`
As far as I know the method is a graphical approach.
So to apply it to following example :

```
Connected components of {{1,1},{1,2},{1234512345,1234512345},{1234512345,1234512346}} ?
```

*The answer is of course very easy :*

```
Answer : {{{1,1},{1,2}},{{1234512345,1234512345},{1234512345,1234512346}}}
```

but to use `MorphologicalComponents`, we should introduce a rectangle of dimension 1234512345*1234512346. We start with so many unnecessary pixels. That's the point I am not satisfied.

***method 2)*** `ConnectedComponents`

```
ConnectedComponents[{1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 4 <-> 5}]
{{2, 1, 3}, {5, 4}}
```

To apply this method to solve my problem(mentioned on the beginning of this post), we should assert propositions such as followings, one by one. It will put a lot of strain on the RAM.

{50,50} and {50,51} is connected
{50,51} and {50,52} is connected
{50,52} and {50,53} is connected
...
{60,21} and {60,22} is connected
{60,22} and {60,23} is connected
...
{20,20} and {20,21} is connected
{20,21} and {20,22} is connected
...

Also the kernel of mathematica would look for this *Connectivity Table* everytime to get the job done. There is no way to explain mathematica kernel *what is connectivity?*, **other then offering this bunch of table.**

So I need yet another method. Can you suggest a good method ?
I am almost completely new to this kind of field (connectivity, graph theory, `MorphologicalComponents`)

If possible, you can also answer for the case when diagonal connectivity is also allowed. Thank you!

+-+-+-+-+-+-+- After Henrik Schumacher's answer +-+-+-+-+-+-+-

It works well. Thank you!

[image]

You can get the picture of Euglena in mathematica help file ref/
MorphologicalComponents.

But one a little sad thing is it is fairly slower then `MorphologicalComponents`. For example,

`MorphologicalComponents` **takes 0. seconds**
Schumacher's method **takes 0.15625 seconds**

I will update the post soon!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does this do what you have in mind?

```
pts = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1234512345, 1234512345}, {1234512345, 1234512346}};
edges = Join @@ MapIndexed[
    Thread[{#1, #2[[1]]}] &,
    Nearest[
      pts -> "Index", 
      pts, 
      {\[Infinity], 1}, 
      DistanceFunction -> ManhattanDistance
    ][[All, 2 ;;]]
  ];
SparseArray`StronglyConnectedComponents[SparseArray[edges ->_]]
```

For diagonal connectivity the same code with `ManhattanDistance` replaced by `ChessboardDistance` should work.

**Edit**

At least for the nondiagonal connectivity, this can be sped up by a factor of ten by avoiding `Nearest`. We can do so because we can find out the horizontal neighbors by going through the rows of sparse image matrix. This is easy to do for a matrix in CSR (compressed sparse row) format. For finding out the vertical neighbors, we just do that for the transposed image, too.

First a couple of helper functions:

```
QuickSparseArray[rp_?VectorQ, ci_?MatrixQ, vals_?VectorQ, dims_?VectorQ, background_ : 0] :=
  With[{data = {Automatic, dims, background, {1, {rp, ci}, vals}}},
   SparseArray @@ data
   ];

ThreadCount[] := "ParallelThreadNumber" /. ("ParallelOptions" /. SystemOptions["ParallelOptions"]);

JobPointers[jobCount_Integer?Positive, threadCount_Integer?Positive] :=
   Ceiling[Subdivide[0, jobCount, Min[threadCount, jobCount]]];

cFindHorizontalNeighbors = 
  Compile[{{rp, _Integer, 1}, {ci, _Integer, 2}, {idx, _Integer, 
     1}, {start, _Integer}, {end, _Integer}},
   Block[{bag, col, nextcol, i, j},
    bag = Internal`Bag[Most[{0}]];
    Do[
     Do[
      col = Compile`GetElement[ci, k, 1];
      nextcol = Compile`GetElement[ci, k + 1, 1];
      If[nextcol == col + 1,
       i = Compile`GetElement[idx, k];
       j = Compile`GetElement[idx, k + 1];
       Internal`StuffBag[bag, i];
       Internal`StuffBag[bag, j];
       Internal`StuffBag[bag, j];
       Internal`StuffBag[bag, i];
       ]
      , {k, Compile`GetElement[rp, row] + 1, 
       Compile`GetElement[rp, row + 1] - 1}]
     , {row, start, end}]; Partition[Internal`BagPart[bag, All], 2]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

Now the actual computations:

```
n = Length[A["NonzeroValues"]];
B = QuickSparseArray[A["RowPointers"], A["ColumnIndices"], Range[n], Dimensions[A]];
BT = Transpose[B];

Bptr = JobPointers[Length[B], ThreadCount[]];
BTptr = JobPointers[Length[BT], ThreadCount[]];

edges = Join[
  Join @@ cFindHorizontalNeighbors[B["RowPointers"], B["ColumnIndices"], B["NonzeroValues"], Most[Bptr] + 1, Rest[Bptr]],
  Join @@ cFindHorizontalNeighbors[BT["RowPointers"], BT["ColumnIndices"], BT["NonzeroValues"], Most[BTptr] + 1, Rest[BTptr]]
  ];

components = SparseArray`StronglyConnectedComponents[SparseArray[edges -> _, {n, n}]];
```

Bonus: We can get the colored sparse array with

```
colors = Normal[SparseArray[ Join @@ components -> Join @@ (Range[Length[components]] Unitize[components]), n]];
Acolored = QuickSparseArray[A["RowPointers"], A["ColumnIndices"], colors, Dimensions[A]];
```

Now we can execute `Colorize[Acolored]` and behold.

In principle, one could do a similar thing for the diagonal lookup. I am just not in the modd for that...